# How to track the time changed of datetime picker for `matInput`

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I have the following datetime picker defined in my template:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >
                    <mat-form-field>
                        <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker" [formControl]="dateControl" 
                            (dateChange)="onScheduleDateChanged($event)"
                        placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="element.date" [disabled]="true">
                        
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        
                        <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker [showSpinners]="true" [showSeconds]="true" [stepHour]="1"
                            [stepMinute]="1" [stepSecond]="1" [touchUi]="false" [color]="color" [enableMeridian]="true"
                            [disableMinute]="false" [hideTime]="false">
                        </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
                        {{getDisplayDate(element.date)}}
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
```

I want to catch when the time is changed. The problem I am having is that when my handler `onScheduleDateChanged` is called, the time is not reflected in an argument `$event` passed to my handler `onScheduleDateChanged` (it still contains the old time). I think this is because the handler handles the event `dateChange` not the time changed one. The question is how do I handle the time changed event.

Comment: Could you add a stackblitz reproduction?

Comment: Sorry. It is my mistake. When I retrieve the `value` from the event object the date is correct.